# display region if response from server returns empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There a section in my react native app I want to display when the API gets no data from the server. But with my current implementation, the message gets already displayed and when there's data in the API that is when it disappears, but when the page loads for the first time it shouldn't seen till the API is loaded and there's no data.

VIEW

```
  {
      posts.length === 0 ? 
      <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:20, color:'#36a', fontFamily:'HelveticaNeue-Light', fontWeight:'500'}}>No Posts for this group yet</Text>
    : null
    }
```

CONTAINER

```
state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      posts : [],
    }

  api.get('/groups/'+`${this.state.groupID}`+'/posts').then((response) => {
    let data = response.data.data
    this.setState({posts: data, showLoader: false});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.posts))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ posts.length < 1 && <Text /> }
```

Also in your container code, it might have problems with this.state.groupID since it's not defined - I assume your state is in the constructor?

And the setState() call in the container; the console.log() afterwards isn't guaranteed to have the posts in in it. If you want a guarantee try this instead:

```
this.setState({ posts: data, showLoader: false }, () => console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.posts));
```